# Previous employee falsely claimed my work in resume

Tags: resume, work-experience, conflict, reputation

The secretary before me left the company before I started there. However, she claims on her resume an additional two years after she was gone - this would be when I was there, and the work done during that time is my work alone.

I had made vast improvements and have the proof that this work is mine. The owner of the company (they were in a relationship) backed up her story - as he said - to help her find work. My problem is that this is my work and on my resume.  If my resume comes before someone that has seen hers I will look like the liar and may not ever have the opportunity to explain.

What protection do I have if any?

Comment: Unless you live in a small town or work in a small industry this is unlikely to happen.  Employers get a lot of resumes and I doubt they cross check the dates against each other.  Even if they did who's to say you both weren't working there at the same time?  I think you're worrying about nothing. :)

Answer (score 7):

Like the others, I don't see that you have anything to worry about.

But, if you need something to put your mind at ease - which of you can show pay slips for those two years?

That seems irrefutable, and should stop you worrying; although,  again, there is almost certainty nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

With the greatest of respect you are worrying about nothing. Irrespective of her "deal" which says that she worked more than she did, your work history stands alone. You worked from then till now, it's that simple. You put that on your cv / resume and forget about her and any lies anyone else wants to say about her, move on.

Unless he's trying to say you worked less, in which case give him hell.. As for protection there is none really, depending on where your at. Just be sure not to apply for the same jobs as her! lol. Mind you if you do you still have the "nuclear" option up your sleeve if you choose to use it. (the truth). Best of luck. T

Answer (score 1):

Why did you see her CV? On her and the owners behalf this was incredibly stupid that you saw the CV at all. The positive side: you learned something about your employers ethics and professional standard. The question is less if you look like a liar but if the person who may write your reference appears to be one.

Answer (score -4):

I would strongly advise against it, but you do have the nuclear option: tell her current employer that she lied on her CV.  They are quite likely to fire her immediately, and might even call the police for fraud.